# One Name server Multiple vps

Tags: vps, nameserver

I have upto 20 vps with static IP each, 
i would like to create a name server like 
ns1.example.com
ns2.example.com

this name server will be used for the 20 vps and the domains hosted in them, instead of creating name servers for each vps.

Please what are the instructions to achieve this.

Comment: You don't.  The specs for DNS require a.minimum of 2 name servers for good reason.  By asking the question you are evidencing that you have no understanding of DNS, so leave it to your domain registrar - most of them offer free DNS.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DNS servers would be expected to contain multiple records and operate as a standalone service. They are the databases of the domain name system. Plural, because more than one is expected for availability of this critical service.

Server Fault does not do product recommendations in general, like what DNS software to use. However, given your lack of an existing DNS infrastructure, I recommend starting with your domain registrar or hosting provider's managed DNS service. Generally inexpensive and higher availability than what you might put on a single virtual machine.

Later, if and when you attempt to create your own authoritative DNS servers, come back with questions.